# How to create an activexobject using ip address in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was trying the below code and getting "Automation server can't create object" error.

function    GetAppVersion(){

```
var XLApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application", "ipaddress"); 
return(XLApp.Version);
```

}

but if I use new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application") then I am not getting this error.

Please help me to avoid getting error on above code.

Comment: My intention is to create activexobject using ipaddress or servername only

Comment: Keep in mind that this type of object will only work on Internet Explorer, definitely not a good approach in modern web developing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are running this from a web page loaded in Internet Explorer, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6958xykx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Creating an object on a remote server can only be accomplished when Internet security is turned off.

Turn off Internet Security.

Comment: could you please tell me how to turn off internet security?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/internet-explorer/ie-security-privacy-settings#ie=ie-11 (under security zones)